# Как пропустить старые сообщения в Telegram.Bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Использую c# библиотеку Telegram.Bot. При старте бота в обработку попадают все пришедшие до запуска сообщения. Можно ли обрабатывать только новые обновления? (Например в aiogram можно указать skip_updates=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я получал дату сообщения

```C#
var date = update.Message!.Date;
```

Далее сравниваю время.

```html
               var datemes = DateTime.Now - (date.AddHours(3));
                if (datemes.Seconds > 5) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Старое сообщение");

                }
```

Если сообщение написали больше 5 секунд назад то просто вывожу в консоль `"Старое сообщение"`, бот юзеру ничего не отвечает.

Comment: а зачем нужен date.AddHours(3)?

Comment: А вот это и доля меня вопрос) Я писал бота год назад и вот не помню зачем я это сделал)

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan times = DateTime.UtcNow - update.Message.Date;
if(times.TotalMinutes > 3)
{
     Console.WriteLine("skipping old update");
}
```

Вот так вот должны мы пропускать старое обновление, получая дату отправки сообщения, делаем переменную times (**update.Message.Date** в формате UTC), а дальше, если итоговое кол-во минут превышают 3 - скипается старый апдейт